# Charging a batch of credit cards

Tags: php, mysql

I have user subscriptions in my DB, and the SUBSCRIPTIONS table has UID (that I use with the CC company to charge the Card), and DATE_EXPIRED, DATE_PAID, VALID and LENGTH.

I am going to need to use some kind of a function to process a batch of subscriptions from the DB and send to the CC company for processing, and upon return, I should treat the subscription accordingly.

in the case the charge went ok, I mark VALID = 1, set DATE_PAID = NOW(), SET DATE_EXPIRED = NOW + INTERVAL LENGTH MONTH
but if the result is not ok, I need to mark VALID = ERROR_NO and do some actions, like sending an email, bring up messages etc.

My question is about the approach to the situation,
I will be getting a list of subscriptions that need to be updated, so:

1. What do you think is the best way to process a batch like that? 
   My internal processing function is using cURL to contact the CC server, and gets a cURL response. upon which I know what to do next.
   Is it a file I should write all necessary subscriptions to ? Is that a cURL to my own server to batch independently ? How do I send a batch of result for processing to myself ? What do you think is the best approach ?
2. How do I keep the SELECT result to process in one time ?
   I think I should clarify. Say I theoretically have 100,000 results, I think I should seperate my SELECT to portions with LIMIT X,Y then put in memory and save on memory, but on the next SELECT I will be casting upon a perhaps different table (as it might have been updated by now). I'd like to run through all 100,000 results having the same 100,000 I had in the first SELECT. Doing all the process in the page would be uneffective of course as the whole process would drop as soon as you close the page.

Comment: The 100k operations is presumably renewing subscriptions - can you do this in a scheduled process offline, like with cron?

Comment: Just as an aside, you're not actually handling credit card numbers yourself, are you?

Comment: I don't hold CC themselves, but I have a CID that I use with the CC company to identify the CC that they hold for me

Comment: ok that's something I was worried about too. and yes, I'd recommend using a cronjob for these purposes, too.

Comment: Please stop writing tags in your titles, and signatures in your posts.

Comment: well, basically cron should be another process that should run daily, but I need this solution for a normal website operation. Plus, It would help me to know how to accomplish that 'genuine' SELECT issue even if it is in the cron tab.

Comment: sorry for that, #Lightness Race in orbit, wouldn't happen again...what signatures ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LOCK TABLES subscriptions WRITE` to solve your second problem, and `UNLOCK` the table when you are done. Although really, unless you're running this on a server with no RAM at all, keeping these 100,000 rows in memory and going through them in a `while` loop using something like `mysql_fetch_assoc` or `mysqli_fetch_assoc` shouldn't be a problem.

As to your first question, why don't you simply process the cURL response when you get it, and save the results in the database on a per-subscription basis? I don't really see why you would want to put this into a separate file first, and certainly not why you would then need to use cURL to contact your own server?

Comment: The processing of a credit card can take a second. So processing many of those in the page that served the client might result in a page close and the server would stop processing the page. I want the server to comfortably process the whole thing regardless of user activity.

Comment: OK but then the question is why you would want this to run as a web page anyway? I can't see that working out for you...assuming you can make 100,000 asynchronous requests to your payment provider (and that's a big if), what would happen if the user hit the stop button in his browser, or if his computer / internet connection failed? Apache would kill the PHP script. Much better to implement this by having a PHP script which the user can access over the web, which then fires up a separate PHP thread using the `at` daemon, and immediately tells the user that processing has been started.

Comment: (Your separate PHP script would then do the processing; you should still design for failure, though, because you wouldn't want a power failure after 90,000 subscriptions have been processed to require recharging these 90,000 CCs so you can be sure these customers have paid!)

Comment: Could you please explain what an at daemon is? where can I read about PHP threads ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8457943/should-i-use-at-now-or-ampersand-to-run-the-script-in-background (and for both questions, a simple Google search will yield a lot of results, too).

Comment: Ok, got it, I like the shell command approach. I thought I'd have a file called "process_subscriptions.php" that should be getting an array of subscriptions, and process the subscriptions one by one, each time UPDATEing the DB for VALID etc. But then again, how do I send that array to that file ? (I am not a Unix expert, I use XAMPP on my windows machine, for development)

Comment: Well, the script'd be getting that data from the database, right? Why use an array?

Comment: Yeah, I am not sure either why this would be a web page. To what sort of user would it be relevant to process 100k credit card transactions in a web request for? Maybe a sysadmin?

Comment: I guess I need to synch in with you guys. I thought that I'd simply have the process_subs.php with a simple GET process_subs.php?group_id=464&cid=5626 and call that with a system command (thus, a shell command) am I correct ? - is it safe to use if it is put inside a protected folder (outside the server's root, for example includes folder ?)

Comment: I'm sorry, but that's just not making a whole lot of sense to me. It may be an idea to discuss this with some other people working on your web site? That way you'll at least have people to discuss this with who actually know your specific usage requirements and the infrastructure you have available, and they may be able to help better. Good luck!

Comment: @Ted - Ah, I think you're of the view that all PHP has to be run through a web server - it doesn't. So an offline process can be run at the command line simply using `php myprocess.php` - or the same can be run on a cron. Daan is also right that something in a web process could kick off a background process in PHP - see the SO link Daan provided, or look at Gearman for background processing, or maybe RabbitMQ for a queue approach. (They can get a bit complex, though :-) )

Comment: I am the only one, for now, who is in charge of the website. I know what need to happen, and the thing is that upon one page request, a series of transactions need to be carried out with the cc company (which as I said, can take some time). Of course I will be glad to hear what actually happens when a user closes the browser abruptly. Does the server finish generating the whole page, or does it stop at some time? If it goes through all the way, of course it might solve the whole thing! So. 1. There will be a cron job processing the whole subscriptions, but for groups, I need to process a batch

Comment: That will 2.process a subset of the subscriptions. What I think about now, is how I can accomplish that safely as it seems quite prone to hacks as I am using a system command from the web page, but I can't verify session data once that process is run. So the system command cannot be protected